# Create Dynamic Threads in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, multithreading, thread-safety

I need to create a dynamic threads in c# which will execute my data table rows.

For example : i had 10000 rows in data table so,i need to create 10 thread and each thread will execute 1000 records at a time.

If my tables rows will increase then threads creation also need to be increase

Normally, we create one thread and it will execute whole 10000 records, i need to threads dynamically which will execute my 10000 records in a split format and which will increase my performance of application.

if i had created a 4 threads to execute my 10000 records and each thread will execute 2500 records.

1st thread will execute from 0 to 2500 records
2nd thread will execute from 2501 to 5000 records
3rd thread will execute from 5001 to 7500 records
4th thread will execute from 75001 to 10000 records

For above example here i had decided 4 threads to created i want it should be in a dynamic way

Comment: Please include more information, maybe post some examples of code you have written?

Comment: This sounds very unusual, perhaps you want a message queue and scale-out based on queue length? Could you share more about the problem you are trying to solve

Comment: Look up `Parallel.ForEach()`, it will do all that without any hassle.

Comment: The optimal nr of threads depends on your CPU, not on the size of your data.

Comment: Just don't do it like that!

Comment: then what to do ? need help

Answer (score 1):

Your question lacks the details but I think you are looking for a **throttling** mechanism. There are plenty of the existing libraries that can do the heavy lifting for you, e.g. https://nugetmusthaves.com/Tag/throttling

You can also implement it yourself. The implementation details will be different for sync and async code.

https://blog.briandrupieski.com/throttling-asynchronous-methods-in-csharp